# Dojo - Add an External stylesheet outside of the header

Tags: javascript, css, dojo, stylesheet, external

I would like to add an external style sheet specified inside of an Ajax call.

I have found a way to do this with jQuery (see the example below), however i need to adapt the method to the dojo JavaScript framework.

### JQuery Example

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightbox_stylesheet.css">');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've included [`dojo.NodeList-manipulate`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/NodeList-manipulate.html), it's virtually identical to jQuery:

```
dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-manipulate");

dojo.ready(function(){
    dojo.query("head").append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightbox_stylesheet.css">');
});
```

Comment: The `dojo.require("dojo.NodeList-manipulate");` line needs to be right at the top of your code/file, like straight after `<script>`  (or something like that, I'm not particularly familar with Dojo). Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/e9q2u/

Comment: @thirtydot: dojo.requires just need to be before anything that uses the module (unless you use a XDomain build, in whick case you need to put all the code inside dojo.ready)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using dojo.query

```
dojo.query("head").forEach(function(node, index, array){
// append content af final of head
node.innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightbox_stylesheet.css">';});
```

Comment: `dojo.query("head")[0].innerHTML += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lightbox_stylesheet.css">';`.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with

After a little messing around i've come up with the following:

```
function require_css(href)
{
   if (typeof href == 'undefined' || href.length == 0) return false;

   var link = dojo.create("link", 
   {
      type  : "text/css",
      rel   : "stylesheet",
      href  : href
   });

   dojo.doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
   console.log("loading : css : "+ href);
}
```

Thanks for the input guys.. I prefer thirtydot's method to mine :D..